# Find folders NOT containing a particular filemask

Tags: windows-7, search

Is there a program or Windows Search trick to display a list of folders NOT containing a particular filemask? Specifically, I want to find all folders not containing a .exe file.

Comment: Including all subfolders? That is a pretty simple thing to code, I'm kind of amazed there's nothing on that front.

Comment: Does it need to be a GUI tool? Or would a Powershell script be okay for your purposes?

Comment: Definitely looking for a GUI tool. I could've written a script myself, but chose instead to seek out something I'd want to use long-term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the shareware [XYplorer](http://www.xyplorer.com/index.php), which has a 30-day trial period.  In [version 14.80](http://www.xyplorer.com/release_14.80.htm), it introduced the feature that you want:

> **Find Containing Folders.** Now you can list all folders containing a certain file or file type, files of a certain size or age, or with certain other properties. You can as well list all folders NOT containing such files.

Comment: Seems to work. Accepting this answer for now, but if anyone finds a free tool specifically for this purpose (I don't need the thousands of other features in XYplorer and would never pay for it), I'm open to switching.